# Javascript popup with error messages from class

Tags: javascript, asp.net

is it possible to make a javascript popup that shows the error text from a article class in aspx, I am not able to change in the form1, and want to show the error message as a popup

[image]

Comment: Very likely yes. Perhaps you can share some code and a better example? For example when is the error available in the HTML? Do you need to monitor changes to the DOM? Is it Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this? Assuming the error is in the HTML at load time

```
window.addEventListener("load", ()  => {
  const errors = [...document.querySelectorAll(".validationerror")]
    .map(article => article.querySelector("h3").textContent);
  if (errors.length > 0) alert(errors.join("\n"));
})
```

Comment: Det var så lidt :)